# pyInstaller having trouble bundling a package containing SWIG modules

Tags: python, swig, pyinstaller

I’m running into an issue getting pyInstaller to bundle a module that contains SWIG modules.  I have followed each of the guidelines listed in the pyInstaller doc which details SWIG support.
I get the following error when running the exe:

```
# sphinxbase._ad_win32 not found in PYZ
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "StartListening.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\allen\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\sphinxbase\__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\allen\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\sphinxbase\ad_win32.py", line 32, in <module>
  File "site-packages\sphinxbase\ad_win32.py", line 31, in swig_import_helper
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sphinxbase._ad_win32'
```

However, sphinxbase._ad_win32 does exists as a pyd file.  I’m running Windows 10; why is pyInstaller having trouble bundling this module?
The third-party package I’m ultimately trying to import is SpeechRecognition which depends on pocketsphinx which depends on sphinxbase which is the module that is having issues.

Here is the object reference returned by

```
importlib.import_module('sphinxbase._ad_win32')
```

in the SWIG-generated python wrapper if that is helpful to someone:

```
<module 'sphinxbase._ad_win32' from 'C:\\Users\\bob\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\lib\\site-packages\\sphinxbase\\_ad_win32.pyd'>
```

Python version: 3.6.5

Edit: After some more research, I tried adding the .pyd to the 'binaries' list in the .spec file as well as adding 'sphinxbase._ad_win32' to the 'hidden-imports' list and combinations there-between, but this did not work either.  The binary is there, in the correct location, I can't figure out why the bundled app can't find it.

Comment: I ran into this issue with a swig-generated library on MacOS. Solved it by adding the relevant dylibs to `binaries` - in my case `_mypaintlib.cpython-37m-darwin.so`. Search for things called `*cpython*.dll`.